# RxJS pipes undefined

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm running a json-server database with some random data:

```
{
  "status": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "uid": 1,
            "isActive": false
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "uid": 3,
            "isActive": true
        }
    ]
}
```

and I'm using this function to fetch some data:

```js
export async function getStatus(uid: number): Promise<Status>{
    return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/status?uid=${uid}`).then(res => res.json())    
}
```

And then, when I run this code:

```js
function isActive(id: number): Observable<boolean>{
    
    return from(getStatus(id))
        .pipe(map(value => {
                console.log (`Value of in map pipe: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)
                return value.isActive
            })) 
}

function main() {
    isActive(1).subscribe({
            next: (value => console.log('answer: ' + value))
        })                 
}

main()
```

it returns this output:

```
Value of in map pipe: [{"id":3,"uid":1,"isActive":false}]
answer: undefined // <-----
```

The expected output:

```
Value of in map pipe: [{"id":3,"uid":1,"isActive":false}]
answer: false // <-----
```

Why do I get undefined instead of false?

Comment: Did you actually _read_ the value you've carefully logged out? What type is it? Do things of that type have an isActive property?

Comment: Did you actually read the value you've carefully logged out? yes. What type is it? `{"id": number,"uid": number,"isActive":boolean}` . Do things of that type have an isActive property? yes

Comment: Evidently you didn't, because: no, it's not.

Comment: Well never mind, I figured it out. getStatus(id) is supposed to return a promise<{"id": number,"uid": number,"isActive":boolean}>  but it returns an array instead. Weird

Comment: That's what happens when you give the compiler the wrong information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your console log I can see a array.
This code will work:

```
function isActive(id: number): Observable<boolean>{
    
    return from(getStatus(id))
        .pipe(map(value => {
                console.log (`Value of in map pipe: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)
                return Array.isArray(value) ? value[0].isActive : false; // you can replace false with value.isActive
            })) 
}
```